# Determine XBee Packet Route

Tags: xbee

I am trying to build a ZigBee network using XBee Pro S2 devices (API Mode).
Setting up the network and sending packets is easy enough.

Is it possible to trace the route a packet travelled from the end-device to the coordinator?

Example: 

I have 2 routers, one in area A connected to the coordinator, and the other in area B connected to the router in area A. End-device enters area B, and transmits a packet to the coordinator. 
**Path: end-device->routerB->routerA->Coordinator**. 

Is it possible to know the end-device is in area B as it is the first router device the packet travelled through?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by  “Coordinator”.  If it's an ordinary computer, run [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) (or tracert) on it

Comment: The "Coordinator" refers to the device type used in the ZigBee network protocol. Every network must have at least one Coordinator. Just note, the ZigBee mesh network is not like standard WiFi protocol. But thank you, I found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is done by using [Source Routing](https://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Large_ZigBee_Networks_and_Source_Routing)

The 16-bit addresses of the hopped devices are added to the RF payload space, thus it will reduce the number of bytes that can be sent in one RF packet.